# why minImageWidth, minImageHeight not working krajee fileInput plugins?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with Krajee file input plugins http://plugins.krajee.com/file-image-dimensions-demo#min-image-dimensions

I want to set min width and min height but It's not working no error in console and no error message in input file.

But max width and max height work correctly it show errror like below in input file.

```
Width of image file "600x380.jpg" cannot exceed 100 px.
Height of image file "600x380.jpg" cannot exceed 100 px.
```

Here is my code

```
<input id="diePhotoxyz" type="file" class="form-control file-loading" style="margin-bottom:0px" name="photo">


    $('#diePhotoxyz').fileinput({
        showUpload: false,
        showCaption: false,
        showPreview: true,
        minImageHeight: 50,
        minImageWidth: 50,
        maxImageHeight: 100,
        maxImageWidth: 100
    });
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure the image you are uploading has width/height of at least 50 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('#diePhotoxyz').fileinput({
    showUpload: false,
    showPreview: true,
    minImageHeight: 50,
    minImageWidth: 50,
    maxImageHeight: 100,
    maxImageWidth: 100
});
```

Comment: You should break down what is different in your proposal that fixes the stated problem.